# How to update subscriber status of a subscriber in all subscribers present in a child BU using landing page present in other child BU?

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, ssjs, soap

I have created a SOAP envelope to invoke all subscribers present in a child Business Unit (BU) from another child BU using a landing page. By utilizing WS Proxy in my landing page located in CHILD BU 1, I intend to modify the status of subscribers in CHILD BU 2. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<script type="javascript" runat="server">
Platform.Load("core",1);
var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();

var accountId: YOURMID
prox.resetClientIds(); // resets current account id;
prox.setClientId({"ID": accountId}); // impersonates other BU
</script>
```

`prox.setClientId` might do the trick alone.
Havent found the pattern when you *have* to use resetClientIds, but in case you switch multiple times, it can make sense.
Have seen no negative effects either.

Comment: accountId be will be the MID of the target BU, and there is no need of creating package right in the target  child BU and how can I add unsub  ssjs in the syntax provided ?

Comment: Yes; no, WSProxy works without package;  I'd suggest opening a separate question / just search for LogUnsubEvent and WSProxy.